# Conditions in Switch Statements

Tags: javascript, statements

I'd like to add more conditions inside my case system. Is there any way (besides loops or if/else if  statements) I can use to incorporate more conditions?

```
<body>

 <input id="input" type="text" placeholder = "Type 'Help1' for actions"/><button onclick="button()">Confirm</button>
     <p id="message"></p>



<script>


    function button() {
    var text;
    var textInput = input.value;
    switch (textInput) {
    case "Help1":
    text = "[Page 1 of 2. Type 'Help2' for page 2] Commands you can use: <ul><li>South</li><li>North</li><li>East</li><li>West</li><li>North Again</li><li>South again</li>";
    document.getElementById("message").style.color = "white";

        break;

    case "Help2":
        text = "[Page 2 of 2] Commands you can use: <li>North One More</li><li>East Once More</li><li>West Once More</li><li>South Once More</li><li>East Again</li><li>West Again</li>";
        document.getElementById("message").style.color = "white";

        break;
case "east again":
text = "You went to city street 1. Do you want to explore?";
document.getElementById("message").style.color = "white";


    break;


default:
        text = "Unknown Command. Type 'Help1' for a list of commands";
        document.getElementById("message").style.color = "white";

    break;

    }

    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = text;
    }
```

For the question regardin East, "do you want to explore?" I want 2 conditions:

Condition 1:
Yes -> Outcome for yes: "You found something fun to do"
No -> Outcome for no: "You decided to not explore and decided to head to another direction"

I have tried multiple ways and ideas but they're not working out for me. If someone has an idea that works and gives the desired outcomes listed above, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean a solution like not structuring your entire program as one single monster switch statement? In one word - functions, functions, functions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM

Comment: I'm unclear, you call this switch statement, it returns its case and writes to the DOM. From there, the user does some other kind of input, right? That should call a different function with a different set of switch cases.